# Executar fastlane com drone IO remoto

Tags: ios, testes-de-unidade

Estou com a seguinte pipeline para executar testes do fastlane num projeto ios:

```
kind: pipeline
name: default

steps:
- name: test
  image: appleboy/drone-ssh
  settings:
    host: host.localhost
    username: fulano
    password: senha
    port: 22
    script:
    - cd projetos/ios/
    - git pull https://gitlab-ci-token:zsdfddW2@projeto.git
    - fastlane test
```

Os dois primeiros comandos funcionam, porém quando rodo fastlane test ele diz que não conhece o comando, fastlane roda no mac normalmente, está setado no path.

Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foi necessário informar o PATH que estava no mac local no momento de executar os comandos. De um export PATH=.... ficando assim:

```
kind: pipeline
name: default

steps:
- name: test
  image: appleboy/drone-ssh
  settings:
    host: host.localhost
    username: fulano
    password: senha
    port: 22
    script:
    - cd projetos/ios/
    - git pull https://gitlab-ci-token:zsdfddW2@projeto.git
    - export PATH=COLOQUE_AQUI_SEU_PATH_LOCAL_DO_MAC
    - fastlane test
```

Comment: se possível, complemente a resposta com a solução completa ou exemplo e não apenas parte do código